# Indented Hierarchical Collapsible grouped data to Columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

**I am trying to change the hierarchical collapsible data to columns in excel ? is there a quick way ?**

I have tried using text to columns but I don't think its a right way.

[image]

Data Previous

[image: Data Previous]

Data After

[image: Data After]

```
+------------+-------+--------+
|    Item    | Level | Parent |
+------------+-------+--------+
| P1         |     1 | N/A    |
|     P2     |     2 | P1     |
|     P3     |     2 | P1     |
|         P4 |     3 | P3     |
|     P5     |     2 | P1     |
|         P6 |     3 | P5     |
+------------+-------+--------+
```

Indented hierarchy to columns. I have tried trim function to count the leading spaces if i will know the count i can simply filter and copy paste data into respective columns but i couldnt count somehow.

Comment: Well, ok we are going step by step: What have you researched or tried so far. Note that this is no free code writing service ([ask]).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Returning the indentation with an easy VBA code

```
Function PROFEXIndentLevel(Cell As Range)
    'This function returns the indentation of a cell content

    Application.Volatile
    'With "Application.Volatile" you can make sure, that the function will be recalculated once the worksheet is recalculated
    'for example, when you press F9 (Windows) or press enter in a cell

    PROFEXIndentLevel = Cell.IndentLevel
    'Return the IndentLevel

End Function
```

Copy and paste this code into a new VBA module. Therefore (as usual) go to the Developer ribbon. Then click on Editor, right click on Microsoft Excel Objects. Insert a new module. Paste the code into this module.

Next, you just have to type the formula `=PROFEXIndentLevel`. For example in cell C3:

```
=PROFEXIndentLevel(A3)
```

In this example you'll get 2 as the return.

Please note that if you use this formula on a large amount of cells it can slow down your workbooks performance.